# Why is the output of this expression different when the variable is replaced with what it is calculating anyways?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Here's the code segment. It's performing `x/2^n`, rounding towards 0. The first print statement calculates the correct value (-7 in this case), but the second statement, which is just the first statement with `bias` replaced with `((x>>31) & ((1<<n)+0xffffffff))` (what bias is calculating anyways) and produces 9. What's going on here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 0x80000004;
    int n = 0x1c;
    int bias = ((x>>31) & ((1<<n)+0xffffffff));
    printf("%d\n", (x + bias) >> n);
    printf("%d\n", (x + ((x>>31) & ((1<<n)+0xffffffff))) >> n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most of those hex literals are unsigned ints, not regular ints.

Comment: @user2357112 Correct me if I'm wrong, the expression calculating bias is unsigned because 0xffffffff is unsigned and all signed ints are casted to unsigned implicitly. Bias is casted to signed when stored in an int variable, and x is signed , so x+bias is signed. But the second expression has the expression for bias, which is unsigned, so x is implicitly cast to unsigned, making the whole thing unsigned, creating the wrong value.

Comment: @justincai   variable bias has the type int.....

Comment: @justincai: Yup, that's what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions `x + bias` and `x + ((x>>31) & ((1<<n)+0xffffffff))` have different types; the first is an `int`, the second an `unsigned int`. The operator `>>` preserves the sign bit for `int`s, but not for `unsigned`s. (The compiler does not *have to* do this, but it *may* do this.) To see clearly what's going on, I have expanded the code a little:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 0x80000004;
    int n = 0x1c;
    int bias = ((x>>31) & ((1<<n)+0xffffffff));
    printf("%d\n", (x + bias) >> n);
    printf("%d\n", (x + ((x>>31) & ((1<<n)+0xffffffff))) >> n);
    printf("%d\n", (x + (int)((x>>31) & ((1<<n)+0xffffffff))) >> n);

    printf ("(int)      %d\n", x + bias);
    printf ("(unsigned) %u\n", x + ((x>>31) & ((1<<n)+0xffffffff)));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
-7
9
-7
(int)      -1879048189
(unsigned) 2415919107
```